# Dynamic scripts are not searchable in IE11 debugger

Tags: internet-explorer-11, javascript-debugger

This happens in IE11 - when I open the file selection menu (Ctrl+O), then files inside the "Dynamic scripts" can be selected/opened, but are not searchable - for example I can click on `_add-to-unscopables.js` to open it  but if I type its name, it would tell me no results were found.

[image]
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is by design, we could only filter the actual script file under our web site.